# ErlIDE on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, macos, erlang

is there anyone successfully using ErlIDE / Eclipse on Mac OS X Mavericks?

I have successfully installed it on Windows but I usually work on a Mac.

I tried with Eclipse 3.7, 4.2.2, 4.4, with no luck.
The IDE goes 'not responding' after a few keystrokes on the source editor. 
In the rare moments of awakens it has *wonderful* hot code update features which are really good especially for those accustomed to Eclipse in the Java world. 
I tried to follow the suggestions here:

https://github.com/erlide/erlide/wiki/Troubleshooting

especially when it says:

> "For Macs, an alternative solution is to rename your computer from
>   foo.whatever to just foo (or anyhting without any dots)."

If I do this, apparently I cannot start an erlang instance with long name as in

```
erl -name foo
```

with erl crashing loudly.
My currently installed Java version is 1.8.0.

Has anyone managed to have ErlIDE up and running smoothly on Mac?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Earlier I've encountered simillar issue (but under linux). My problem was in that host couldn't resolve their own hostname. Does you machine could ping itself by hostname? `ping ${HOSTNAME}`. If it doesn't, try to add appropriate alias to `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

*Not really an answer, but still you could find it useful*

To be honest I don't know anyone using ErlIDE.  Most of my colleagues use emacs (so do I), some use Vim, and lately quite few are using [Erlang IntelliJ plugin](http://ignatov.github.io/intellij-erlang/).

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is super great IDE, you can get it for free (full featured from Erlang's point of view), and plugin is actively developed.

Comment: Thank you mpm!
 I tried it as well, but as far as I can see it does not have the 'hot code replace' feature that makes ErlIDE potentially stand out. 
Perhaps do you know if it is possible to have such feature either with emacs or with IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: (assuming you do not mean [app upgrades](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/relups)) No; not in IDE. [EDTS](https://github.com/tjarvstrand/edts) will recompile and reload module in somewhat "internal Erlang node". But I use [sync](https://github.com/rustyio/sync) for this, but there is also little older [reloader](https://github.com/oinksoft/reloader) and newer [active](https://github.com/synrc/active)